# Performance-wise, is it better to enqueue a (small) script on every page or test to see if it's needed?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, conditional-content, optimization

I'm using the [FitVids.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js) script to make YouTube video embeds work with a responsive layout. The script is < 3kb, but only about half of my pages actually have YouTube embeds.

In terms of total load-time for a page that doesn't contain a YouTube video, is it more costly to do a `strpos()` on the content or to include the script regardless?

I imagine this has a lot to do with the end-user's connection speed vs. the server's resources, and honestly, it's a low-traffic site with undemanding users so it really doesn't matter... I'm mostly asking because I don't have a good grasp of performance optimization and I want to learn.

Comment: This is not really a WordPress-specific question … try a different site listed in the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: To be clear, I'm specifically wondering about any performance hit incurred by accessing $post->post_content on every page load.

You could simplify the question down to: how costly is it to read and compare that value as part of a wp_enqueue_scripts action?

As mentioned, I'm not clear on the performance impact, so even a "it's a trivial amount of processing impact" or "you'd want to think twice" would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens on the user’s side is off topic as @bungeshea said already. Once the user has loaded the file it will stay in the browser cache for a while, so you don’t have to worry about double loaded files anyway.

But let’s look at the server side and how WordPress handles this.

If you want to load a script on every page you just hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_fitvid' );

function load_fitvid()
{
    wp_register_script( 'fitvid', plugins_url('/fitvid.js', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fitvid' );
}
```

Dead simple.

If you want to load the script only if there is a YouTube video, you have to hook into `the_content`, search for URLs with a host name `youtube.com` or `youtu.be`, check if `WP_Embed::autoembed` is activated (this converts URLs into embeds) and load the script if all these conditionals evaluate to `TRUE`.

This is slower. It is not very safe too: the default handler for videos might be overridden and run later than your content parser.

So: yes, there is a difference. I would use the simple method in your situation. If just 1% of all posts had a video … well this would be a different situation. I would hook into `save_post` then and update a custom meta value `load_fitvid`. On the front-end I’d test that value (much faster) and load the script then. But this is rather difficult to implement with existing posts.